# How To play radio app in background and show Widget on notification bar?

Tags: android, background, widget, android-mediaplayer, internet-radio

Considering this code:

```
package com.radio.radiostar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import java.io.IOException;


 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private final static String RADIO_STATION_URL = "http://178.32.137.180:8665/stream";

private ProgressBar playSeekBar;

private Button buttonPlay;

private Button buttonStopPlay;

private MediaPlayer player;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initializeUIElements();

    initializeMediaPlayer();
}

private void initializeUIElements() {

    playSeekBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    playSeekBar.setMax(100);
    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

    buttonStopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopPlay);
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
    buttonStopPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == buttonPlay) {
        startPlaying();
    } else if (v == buttonStopPlay) {
        stopPlaying();

    }
}

private void startPlaying() {
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
    buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);

    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    player.prepareAsync();

    player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            player.start();
        }
    });

}

private void stopPlaying() {
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        initializeMediaPlayer();
    }

    buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}

private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        player.setDataSource(RADIO_STATION_URL);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
            playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
            Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        player.stop();
    }
}


};
```

I want to enable the background play, with a widget on notification bar like "apollo" or any other media player (with only play/pause button and the "x" to close streaming and background).
Can you help me, writing the code that I must use, and in which part of code?
Thanks in advance.
Fabio.

EDIT: I have deleted

```
if (player.isPlaying()) {
        player.p();
```

From

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
   super.onPause();


}
```

And now works in background u.u
I only need to show the widget on notification bar :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to play the stream while the app is minimized? Then you have to user the `Service`. You should move your code to the service. And you will be able to handle notification bar from the service as well.

When you do this, you will probably ask yourself "how can I now update the UI since the player is handled in the service". The answer to this is usage of `BroadcastService` where your Service will broadcast all important data (like timer ticks while stream is active) and your `Activity` has to catch those data and use it to fill its own UI.

Since the code for what I described here is huge, you should try implementing a service and broadcast logic first, and if you are stuck, come back here with a concrete question.

Comment: thanks for answering :)
I have a new question: how can i "change" the entire code, actually based on activity into service? I have see some codes that create a radio with the use of service, but i'm a bit stucked to the "conversion" of my code..
Also, i have tried to add a broadcast and a service, but i had error, using activity :/

Comment: You should move all your `MediaPlayer` logic to the service class. And in it you play the stream. You can bind the start button in the `Activity` to start the service, for example.

Comment: Also, you may not need broadcasting actions if your service isn't sending any data to your activity.

Comment: My app it's created only to receive the streaming audio :) @sandalone
So, i need only the "notification" on notification bar, and maybe two control: one for pause/resume , and one for close the app from notification :)

Comment: Your service then has to start and stop sound. Make 2 public methods which play or stop the stream. Also create notification from the service itself. And play/stop buttons from the activity shall call these public methods as well. Not sure what isn't clear when Android developer docs have detailed examples on both Service and MediaPlayer

Comment: MediaPlayer is not classic part of activity class.If i define like public static i can access from classic widget . Is it possible for services also to make access ( click play from notify widget SEND to-> activity to make play) for example (Player defined intro activity)?